# How do I create a keyboard pressing bot in python that doesn't go out of sync?

Tags: python, bots

So I want to create a bot for a video game, the bot needs to move the character so I decided to use the pydirectinput library to simulate the keyboard, the problem is that when I try to do something like:

```
pydirectinput.keyDown('left')
time.sleep(0.5)
pydirectinput.keyUp('left')
```

the `time.sleep()` method just passes the request to the OS and the OS's timing is ± 2-5 ms loose and because I am working with some small-scale movements the result are not accurate and my character doesn't always get to where it needs to be.

I also tried using `pydirectinput.press('left', 5)` but the result are also different every time I  run the code.

Is there any other more accurate method to do that, or do you guys have any other ideas about how I could build this bot?

Comment: I don't think you'll be able to rely on timing alone or else you'll always run into this eventually. Can you have something recording the screen and then make movements depending on what the screen look like?

Comment: I am not sure but your comment gave me an idea. Since it's a 2D videogame and I have to do a repetitive task, I think I can resolve this by mapping a path somehow, I'll look more into this method since you relying on timing is ruled out. Thank you.